# How to show loader overlay until image is loaded on webpage?

Tags: javascript, image, onload, loader

I want to make a loading overlay, but instead using `setTimeout` I would like to show the "loader" until the first image is fully loaded on the webpage. ( After that, I would like to use lazy image loading )

Until now I used setTimeout, but it's not working really well. I can set a bigger time, but now there is a "gap" between the loader and when the image appears.

The picture urls are fetched from a wordpress API and I'm using template.
What I want is to show the "loading" overlay until the first image is fully loaded, so users don't see the blank state.

```
var img = document.querySelector("#img");

img.onload = function(){ 
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none" 
}
```

I can't use jQuery because it's for a school project. I tried all the alternatives I found here by adding a `console.log("loaded")` when it's loaded, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your markup and any relevant CSS? Also, is this to work for many images on a page or just the one?

Comment: Is this the problem? `querySelector("#img")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe set the img.src after you defined onload

```
let img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function(){}
img.src = "url"
```